# How to get object values from Angular local storage.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have an local storage like this :

```
localStorage.setItem("memberdata", JSON.stringify($scope.products));                

                $scope.listdata= localStorage.getItem("memberdata");
                if($scope.listdata){
                    $scope.listdata = JSON.parse($scope.listdata)
                }else {
                    localStorage.setItem("memberdata", JSON.stringify($scope.products));
                }
```

`$scope.products` contains the following JSON data :

```
{
    "member_id": 54,
    "first_name": "Hima",
    "middle_name": "Ganapathy",
    "last_name": "Hegde",
    "joining_date": "2017-28-04",
    "phone": 7411556977,
    "password": "1234",
    "mail": "shivam@abinfosoft.com",
    "system_date": "Apr 28, 2017 2:26:33 PM",
    "society_id": 10,
    "role": [
        {
            "role_id": 4,
            "name": "User",
            "details": "text"
        }
    ],
    "associated": [
        {
            "associated_id": 1,
            "associated_name": "Parent",
            "primary_member_id": 1
        }
    ],
}
```

In my view if I alert I get all thee JSON data tats right.

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("memberdata"));
```

I tried to print member name only but not working. Even thow I putted listdata in $scope of my controller.

```
{{listdata.first_name}} // Working but deleting when page refreshes
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON

```
   $scope.listdata= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("memberdata"))
    console.log($scope.listdata.first_name);
```

**Edit.**
It will not work

```
$scope.listdata = localStorage.setItem("memberdata", angular.toJson($scope.products));//wrong
```

You need to **stringify** JSON before saving it to localstorage.

Like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("memberdata", JSON.stringify($scope.products));
```

Edit 2:

Do like this:

```
$scope.listdata= localStorage.getItem("memberdata");

if($scope.listdata){
    $scope.listdata = JSON.parse($scope.listdata)

}else {
    localStorage.setItem("memberdata", JSON.stringify($scope.products));
}
```

Comment: If I use {{listdata.first_name}} in my view it is null. In console it is showing undefined..

Comment: @PrashanthHarish arue you doing this : $scope.listdata = localStorage.setItem("memberdata", JSON.stringify($scope.products)),

Comment: Yes. You need that to.

Comment: If I refresh the page data is deleting.. I want to stay there nly.. Thats why I used local storage...

Comment: @PrashanthHarish You need to understand the stuff. When page is refrreshed, localstorage is not deleted. Better study the tutorial and understand it.

Comment: I read it thats why I stored member $scope.products in local storage... But I dont know why data is deleting..

Comment: It is deleting because you are  not checking localstorage before adding data to it. Check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

var localMemberdata = localStorage.memberdata;

$rootScope.localMemberdata = JSON.parse(localMemberdata);

**In View**

{{  localMemberdata.first_name }}

if this correct please check it as answer but I'm sure 100% work well

Comment: when you save it into local it should be like this:
localStorage.setItem('localMemberdata ', JSON.stringify($scope.products));

Comment: Reason behind I used local storage is when refresh the page the data should remain. In your case data is deleting after refresh..

Comment: really ? I used this for user authentication but I did not meet that

Comment: I think maybe your have to put condition

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**

```
        var localListdata = localStorage.memberdata;

        if (localListdata ) {

             console.log("true")

          $rootScope.localListdata = JSON.parse(localListdat);

        } else {
            console.log("null")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. The only thing is that provided `JSON` is not a valid `JSON`.

**JSON Validator screenshot :**

[image]

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29559/)**

Comment: Thanks for reply. No wrong in code but while refresh data is deleting in my browser I think my frame work is clearing local storage data...

Comment: It should not happen. I think you are setting blank data in localStorage on page load..remove outer localStorage setItem function.